# What is the derivative of the function $f(x)=ix?$ Is it $i$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, visualization

Why is this? How is $i$ the slope of the function? Where is it the slope?

I understand taking the derivative with the power rule in, for example, the parabola $x^2$ becoming $2x$ and seeing where that is the slope, but I don't understand how dividing two things a number was multiplied by gives you a derivative exactly.

Comment: It is indeed i.

Comment: Is it dy/dx = i? Can it be graphed somehow? I don't understand what is happening here.

Comment: Try graphing it in the argand plane

Comment: "argand plane" Is that on Desmos?

Comment: Argand plane is a [complex-plane](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_plane&ved=2ahUKEwifpdf8pITqAhWVe30KHVqyCRUQmhMwDXoECAUQAg&usg=AOvVaw13QvkziiVci3IzvUami86H) where y axis has imaginary numbers and x axis has real numbers

Comment: "dividing two things a number was multiplied by gives you a derivative exactly": what ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values taken by the function $f  :  x \in \mathbb{R} \, \longmapsto \, ix$ are complex numbers. However that's not a big deal. You can still define the derivative of $f$ using a limit. Given $x \in \mathbb{R}$,

$$ f'(x) = \lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h} = \lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{i(x+h) - ix}{h} = i. $$

Answer (score 2):

You have$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{i(x+h)-ix}h=\lim_{h\to0}i=i.$$But this has nothing to do with the concept of slope. That's from differentiable real functions of one real variable.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of “slope” is a useful intuition when you are learning single variable (real) calculus, but has more general meanings when dealing in higher dimensions.

In particular, the field of complex numbers has dimension $2$ over the reals, so the graph of a function from the reals to the complex has degree $3.$ So “slope” has to be generalized.

A simpler way to think about this case is to think of $f$ as a function of time, $f(t)=it,$ returning a position at time $t.$ Then at time $t$ the velocity vector, the derivative, is $i.$